# get Internal Server Error in .htaccess RewriteRule with dynamic string for start

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, preg-match

this code:

```
RewriteRule   ^([A-Za-z0-9\.]+)/(.*)$   /?p=profile&user_name=$1 [NC,L]
```

Works fine.

but this:

```
RewriteRule   ^([A-Za-z0-9\.]+)/?(.*)$   /?p=profile&user_name=$1 [NC,L]
```

not work and get internal server error!!!

i want both with and without (/) after user name work.
example of thats:

- example.com/myusername/
- example.com/myusername
- example.com/myusername/family
- example.com/myusername/family/

all must work!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by replacing codes with these:

```
RewriteRule   ^([A-Za-z0-9\.]+)$  /?p=profile&user_name=$1 [NC,NS,L]
RewriteRule   ^([A-Za-z0-9\.]+)/(.*)$  /?p=profile&user_name=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's some internal looping of the rules. If you don't have any other rules, I'm not sure what it could be but you can add an explicit check against the query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !user_name
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\.]+)/? /?p=profile&user_name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: this work. but has big problem: all other pages that i Rewrited them, has been redirected to /?p=profile&user_name=$1 page. even main page!!!

Comment: @EmRa228 When you mean "all other pages", do you mean like `example.com/myusername`? or `example.com/page`? or `example.com/something.html`? Because the regex that you had matches all of those, there's going to have to be some kind of difference between a "username" and a "page"